# OverlayItem not showing on correct point on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I've used below code for show GeoPoint on Android map:

```
        drawable            = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.annot_start);
        point               = new GeoPoint((int)(startLatitude*1E6), (int)(startLongitude*1E6));
        overlayItem         = new OverlayItem(point, startAddress, "");
        itemizedOverlay[n]= new RouteItemizedOverlay(getDrawable(drawable), mapView);
        itemizedOverlay[n].addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay[n]);
```

But the pin point is not showing on the current place, it is shown below the point.[image]

How to pin the point on correct position?

Comment: what are your points? make sure you are passing latitude for latitude longitude for longitude

Comment: Route usually doesn't start from the same exact point given as start address, it starts from the nearest road from that start address. You may draw a line from the start point to the first point in the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>` constructor use `super(boundCenterBottom(marker));`. May be it helps.